# Extra threads in solr thread dump dashboard

Tags: java, jvm, solrcloud, thread-dump

I am using solr 5.4.0 with java version "1.7.0_95" and in my solr dashboard I am seeing some threads in WAITING state. I have restarted solr and they are still there. The data in solr dashboard thread dump section is

```
lifecycleSupervisor-13-9 (94)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@7cc5a571
sun.misc.Unsafe.park​(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park​(LockSupport.java:186)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await​(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take​(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take​(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask​(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker​(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run​(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
java.lang.Thread.run​(Thread.java:745)
```

There are 5 to 10 such threads. What do this threads do?
Why are they always in waiting state when nothing is being run on solr?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Some thread pool, possibly?

Comment: They are waiting for a task to be passed the thread pool so it has something to do.

Comment: hey, this threads are actually not related to solr. They are from a third party software that I am using